# how to handle ORA-00001: unique constraint (COMUID.SCANNED_LR_DET_UK1) violated in java

Tags: sql, exception

how to handle ORA-00001 unique constraint violated in java, i am using SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException in java code as primary catch block but executing Exception catch block. How to handle this issue. please help me to find out this problem.

what are the other classes for SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException to handle unique constraint at core java level

Answer (score 0):

**Option #1**
Drop the unique constraint.

**Option #2**
Change the constraint to allow duplicate values.

**Option #3**
Modify your SQL so that a duplicate value is not created.